# Python: Creating instance of collection

Tags: python, collections, outliner

I need to create instance of collection in python and i cant find any way to do this.

Im stuck because i cant find a way to  "set selected" anything in outliner via code
and the console command seems to need that:

bpy.ops.outliner.collection_instance()

Is there a way to tell outliner what item to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to create an instance from a collection named "monkeys":

```py
bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add(collection='monkeys', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

and the [manual entry](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add) describes the arguments.